# Self referencing loop detected where there is none

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a data model made of a `TransformationPlanModel` which in turn contains an `IEnumerable<TransformationModel>`. `TransformationPlanModel` is the root data transfer object. `TransformationModel` is an abstract base class for other transformation models.

Snipped code for `TransformationPlanModel`:

```
public class TransformationPlanModel
{
    // snip
    public IEnumerable<TransformationModel> Transformations { get; set; }
}
```

Snipped code for `TransformationModel`:

```
public abstract class TransformationModel
{
    //snip
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

One of concrete transformation models is `RemoveRowsTransformationModel`:

```
public class RemoveRowsTransformationModel : TransformationModel
{
    public const string KeyConst = "removeRows";

    public int TopRowsCount { get; set; }
    public int BottomRowsCount { get; set; }

    public RemoveRowsTransformationModel()
    {
        Key = KeyConst;
    }

    //snip
}
```

I've written a custom `JsonConverter` which converts the `TransformationModel` inheritance tree. The implementation of `JsonWrite` method is:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JObject.FromObject(value, serializer).WriteTo(writer);
}
```

The custom converter is used in an ASP.NET Core API application and is added to the services in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method like so:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new TransformationConverter());
});
```

When a `TransformationPlanModel` is returned as a response from an API endpoint and is serialized, a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` is thrown containing the message: "Self referencing loop detected with type '(...).RemoveRowsTransformationModel'". What causes this exception? I fail to see where the self referencing loop is. I don't know if it matters, but I'm using .NET Core 2.0 Preview 1.

Interestingly enough, when an overload of `JObject.FromObject` without the serializer parameter is used in the `WriteJson` method, it works properly:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JObject.FromObject(value).WriteTo(writer);
}
```

This however resets the serialization settings, like camel case property naming. I've also tried ignoring the circular references in Json.Net settings, but no transformations are serialized then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "self-referencing loop" the error is referring to in this case is your converter calling itself.  The serializer has settings which direct it to use your converter.  Your converter calls `JObject.FromObject()`, passing in the serializer.  `JObject.FromObject` uses the serializer to to try to create a `JObject` from your model.  The serializer then calls your converter again, and so on.  Json.Net detects this recursive loop and throws an exception.

One possible solution is to use a new serializer instance, copying all the settings from the original serializer except for the converter:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JsonSerializer ser2 = new JsonSerializer();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(JsonSerializer).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.Name != nameof(JsonSerializer.Converters)))
    {
        prop.SetValue(ser2, prop.GetValue(serializer));
    }
    JObject.FromObject(value, ser2).WriteTo(writer);
}
```

However, since your `WriteJson` method doesn't appear to do anything other than just loading the object and immediately writing it out without any changes, a better solution is simply to override `CanWrite` to return false.  Then `WriteJson` will not be called at all and the default serialization will be used instead, which seems to be what you want to happen here anyway.

```
public override bool CanWrite
{
    get { return false; }
}
```